# Spring 4: Multiple base path in one controller

Tags: java, spring, rest, model-view-controller, controller

I have a question about Spring 4.
My controller is accessible from a URL, but I want to have a second URL where only the beginning is different to access the same endpoints of this controller.

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController("MyController")
@RequestMapping(value={"/abc/def/ghi","/ijk/def/ghi"})
public class MyController {
// code continuation
```

But I get this error message.

```
Multiple class level mappings defined on class com.MyController
```

Did I miss something?
Thanks.

Edit : as M. Dudek mentioned, it was indeed necessary to upgrade Hateoas.

Comment: as M. Dudek mentioned, try with 'value' attribute in @RequestMapping (instead of 'values')

Comment: Are you using Hateoas? I found that [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/186) with exactly the same error message.

Comment: Thank you M. Dudek, it was indeed necessary to upgrade Hateoas!

Answer (score 1):

[`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) has a `String[]` `value` parameter (not `values`), so you should be able to specify multiple values like this:

```java
@RequestMapping(value={"/abc/def/ghi"},{"/ijk/def/ghi"})
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I just changed my code.
I had **value** instead of **values** and  

```java
 {"/ abc / def / ghi", "/ ijk / def / ghi"}
```
instead 

```java
{"/ abc / def / ghi"}, {"/ ijk / def / ghi "}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
@RestController("MyController")
@RequestMapping(value={"/abc/def/ghi","/ijk/def/ghi"})
public class MyController {
// code continuation
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I just changed my code.
I had **value** instead of **values** and  

```java
 {"/ abc / def / ghi", "/ ijk / def / ghi"}
```
instead 

```java
{"/ abc / def / ghi"}, {"/ ijk / def / ghi "}
```